# Graphic Calendar in Java

Tags: java, date

Below is shown the code that displays the current month in graphical form. I would like the entire year to be displayed, not just one month. I know that this can be done with a loop. Also, I would like all days except the current month to be grayed out. How can I do this?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    
SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
Date date = new Date();

public void setDate(Date date) {
this.date = date;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
super.paintComponent(g);

g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 17));
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString(month.format(date).toUpperCase(), 34, 36);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString(year.format(date), 235, 36);

g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10));
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.setTime(date);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
for (int week = 0; week < 5; week++) {
    for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
            g.drawString(day.format(cal.getTime()), d * 30 + 46 + 4,week * 29 + 81 + 20);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 280));
Main ch = new Main();
ch.setDate(new Date());
frame.getContentPane().add(ch);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (but not necessarily the best) solution is to add 12 instances of `Main` to a `JFrame` with [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
    Date date = new Date();

    public Main() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 280));
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(month.format(date).toUpperCase(), 34, 36);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(year.format(date), 235, 36);

        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.setTime(date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
        for (int week = 0; week < 5; week++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
                g.drawString(day.format(cal.getTime()), d * 30 + 46 + 4, week * 29 + 81 + 20);
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            Main ch = new Main();
            ch.setDate(new Date(121, i, 1));
            frame.getContentPane().add(ch);
        }
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks.

[image: screen capture of running app]

But why reinvent the wheel? There are already date picker components. For *Swing* there is [JCalendar](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/) and if you are willing to consider JavaFX then there is [Date Picker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHHJBEA).

By the way, is your calendar for display only, or do you intend for the user to interact with it?

Comment: My calendar is only for display.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The [Answer by Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817015/642706) is correct and well done.

Here in this Answer I modify that code to make use of the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible date-time classes. Never use `Calendar`, `Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

My changes include:

- Changing the 1-12 looping for months to looping the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum elements.
- Changing name of class to the more descriptive `MonthPanel`.
- Altering the constructor to take `YearMonth` & `Locale`, while eliminating some of the setter methods.
- Enabling localization by specifying a `Locale` object.
- Tracking each month by [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) object.
- Replacing use of `Calendar`/`Date` with `LocalDate`.
- Getting first day of week per the `Locale` by calling `WeekFields.of( this.locale ).getFirstDayOfWeek()` returning a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object.
- Calculating the first day to appear within every monthly grid of day numbers by calling [`TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( … )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame(java.time.DayOfWeek)), passing a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object.
- Dropping the formatter for month name, using instead [`Month#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) to automatically localize the name of the month.

```java
package work.basil.calendar;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MonthPanel extends JPanel
{
    //-------------|  Member fields  |------------------------------
    private YearMonth yearMonth;
    private Locale locale;
    private DateTimeFormatter yearFormatter;
    private DateTimeFormatter dayFormatter;

    //-------------|  Constructors  |------------------------------
    public MonthPanel ( final YearMonth yearMonth , final Locale locale )
    {
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300 , 280 ) );
        this.yearMonth = Objects.requireNonNull( yearMonth );
        this.locale = Objects.requireNonNull( locale );

        this.yearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu" ).withLocale( locale );
        this.dayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d" ).withLocale( locale );
    }

    // Default to JVM’s current default `Locale` if not specified as argument.
    public MonthPanel ( final YearMonth yearMonth )
    {
        this( Objects.requireNonNull( yearMonth ) , Locale.getDefault() );
    }

    //-------------|  Logic  |------------------------------
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        ( ( Graphics2D ) g ).setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING ,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        g.fillRect( 0 , 0 , getWidth() , getHeight() );
        super.paintComponent( g );

        g.setFont( new Font( "TimesRoman" , Font.PLAIN , 17 ) );

        // Month label
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        String monthName = this.yearMonth.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , this.locale );
        g.drawString( monthName , 34 , 36 );

        // Year label
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        String yearName = yearFormatter.format( this.yearMonth.atDay( 1 ) );
        g.drawString( yearName , 235 , 36 );

        // Each day-of-month.
        g.setFont( new Font( "TimesRoman" , Font.PLAIN , 10 ) );
        LocalDate firstOfMonth = this.yearMonth.atDay( 1 );
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of( this.locale ).getFirstDayOfWeek();
        LocalDate firstDayOfMonthBlock = firstOfMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) );
        LocalDate dateToDraw = firstDayOfMonthBlock;
        for ( int week = 0 ; week < 5 ; week++ )
        {
            for ( int d = 0 ; d < 7 ; d++ )
            {
                // Draw the dayf-of-month.
                String s = dayFormatter.format( dateToDraw );
                g.drawString( s , d * 30 + 46 + 4 , week * 29 + 81 + 20 );
                // Set up the next loop.
                dateToDraw = dateToDraw.plusDays( 1 );  // Replace rather than alter ("mutate") the original object, per immutable objects pattern used by *java.time*.
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Year year = Year.of( 2021 );
        Locale locale = Locale.US;  // Or `Locale.getDefault()`.

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.white );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new GridLayout( 0 , 4 ) );
        for ( Month month : Month.values() )
        {
            YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( year.getValue() , month );
            MonthPanel monthPanel = new MonthPanel( yearMonth , locale );
            frame.getContentPane().add( monthPanel );
        }
        frame.setUndecorated( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).